# new route in yeoman generator redirects to home page

Tags: angularjs, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I am using the yeoman generator generator-angular-fullstack from https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack

I created a project using

```
yo angular-fullstack
```

I then wanted to add a new route in the app which i did using

```
yo angular-fullstack:route myroute
```

I can see the new files being generated like show in the screenshot below
[image]

I see this in myroute.js

```
angular.module('invoice1App')
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/myroute', {
        templateUrl: 'app/myroute/myroute.html',
        controller: 'MyrouteCtrl'
      });
  });
```

But whenever i try to open localhost:port/myroute i get redirected back to the home page. I can't figure this out since last two days. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed /#/ try localhost:port/#/myroute

Comment: it redirects to http://localhost:9000/#%2Fmyroute which still shows the home page

Answer (score 0):

you have to check the **app.js** file. It is in the **scripts** folder

make sure you check the

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) { 
    // the routing 

}
```